# How to send automated emails (coupon site)?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, email

Right now I'm running a coupon site with Wordpress.
I would like to have a function where I can send automated emails which contain printable vouchers to users right after they key-in thier e-mail address. This function is similar to vouchercodes.co.uk printable restaurant vouchers.

How can I do that ?

Comment: use the cron job. set that function in cron job.

Comment: What do you mean by cron job ?

Comment: read this: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/ and http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/what-do-i-put-for-the-cron-job-command

Answer (score 0):

nice neat way.

http://www.phplist.com/

http://www.phplist.com/demo

just export email from wordpress and configure them in PHP list by importing.this would be easy and have tracks too.

Comment: I want to send it instantly when they enter thier email address. How should I do it ?

Comment: their is an default wordpress function add_action( 'i_am_hook', 'who_is_hook');

Comment: you need to make ur hands dirty then @user1498840
their is an default wordpress function **bold**add_action  

Ex
--
add_action( 'call_yourSEND_EMAIL', 'when_userEnter_email');   

assume that when_userEnter_email() used to call when user user enter email,
after the completion of when_userEnter_email() function this call_yourSEND_EMAIL() will be called

see here
[link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action#Example)